# upgrade Jboss As7 installation to Wildfly 10

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jboss-cli

Thanks in advance. I am working on to upgrade JBOSS As7 to Wildfly 10. Manually I am able to do it. But I am looking for scripted solution that works without manual intervention as I need to upgrade 1000s of client. Please suggest some tools or scripts to do this.

Thanks,
Naga

Comment: If anyone suggest me how to use jboss-cli script to do this will be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use CLI scripts to configure a server.
You are able to use variables and use the sript on different installations.
Also you are able to configure a new instance the same way as before.
If you use a newer version the CLI run check whether all is applicable.

I don't think that there is a general tool to migrate the config.
For minor versions you are able to copy the configuration folder, but you might loose new enhancements or features.

Comment: Thanks Wfink, Yes. Fresh configuration makes sense.